Let $f,g:M\rightarrow N$ be smooth maps transverse to $X\subset N$. Are $f^{-1}(X)$ and $g^{-1}(X)$ cobordant?
Let $F,G:M\rightarrow N$ be smoothly homotopic maps so that $F$ and $G$ are transverse to $X\subset N$, are $F^{-1}(X)$ and $G^{-1}(X)$ then cobordant to one another?
I saw this statement in these lecture notes, though they are dealing with oriented cobordism, I feel it shouldn't matter if it is true.
My issue is that they say this follows from the Parametric Transversality theorem, by essentially saying that we can choose a smooth homotopy $H:M\times I\rightarrow N$ that is transverse and I don't think this follows? In particular, the Paremetric transversality theorem states that:

If $H:M\times S\rightarrow N$ is a smooth family of maps parameterized by a smooth manifold with or without boundary, such that $H$ is transverse to $X$, then the induced map $H_s:x\mapsto H(x,s)$ is transverse for almost all $s\in S$

From this statement one can readily obtain that any smooth map $f:M\rightarrow N$ is homotopic to one transvsere to any submanifold of $N$, but I don't think these two statements allow us to pick a smooth homotopy that is itself transverse. In fact, given a smooth homotopy between $F$ and $G$, I do not think we can even always construct a family of smooth maps parameterized by a higher dimensional manifold that is transverse almost everywhere. Am I missing something?

The Transversality Theorem one wants to use here is the following:
Theorem (Differential Manifolds, Tammo tom Dieck, Theorem 1.14.8): Let $f\colon M\rightarrow N$ be a smooth map and $X\subseteq N$ a smooth submanifold. Furthermore, assume $f$ is transverse to $X$ at the points of a closed subset $C\subseteq M$. Then, $f$ is homotopic (rel $C$) to a smooth map $g\colon M\rightarrow N$ s.t. $f\vert_C=g\vert_C$ and $g$ is transverse to $X$.
[Here, $N$ and $X$ are assumed boundaryless and $M$ is permitted boundary.]
This Theorem is proven using Parametric Transversality. The basic idea is to embed $N$ in some $\mathbb{R}^k$ for $k\gg0$, consider a tubular neighborhood of $N$ and then parametrize all the directions in $\mathbb{R}^k$ that we can "move $f$ off of $N$" and apply Parametric Transversality. In case $C=\emptyset$, this is the proof and can be found in standad references. The case allowing arbitrary closed $C$, however, is slightly more technical and typically omitted.
In any case, having this result at our disposal, fix a homotopy $H\colon M\times I\rightarrow N$ from $F$ to $G$. Smooth approximation tells us we can assume that $H$ is smooth w.l.o.g.. Now, $H$ is a smooth map $M\times I\rightarrow N$ and transverse to the smooth submanifold $X\subseteq N$ on the closed subset $M\times\partial I$. Thus, $H$ is homotopic to a smooth map $K\colon M\times I\rightarrow N$ s.t. $K\vert_{M\times\partial I}=H\vert_{M\times\partial I}$, i.e. $K$ is a smooth homotopy from $F$ to $G$, and $K$ is transverse to $X\subseteq N$. Then, it is standard that $K^{-1}(X)\subseteq M\times I$ is a neat submanifold, i.e. a manifold with boundary $\partial K^{-1}(X)=K^{-1}(X)\cap(M\times\partial I)=F^{-1}(X)\sqcup G^{-1}(X)$, and thus a cobordism between $F^{-1}(X)$ and $G^{-1}(X)$.
